# Why did Zenitsu require an incredible breathing technique to get out of simple rubble?

Tags: demon-slayer

Question pertains to Demon Slayer - Entertainment District Arc:

Spoiler:

> I find it hard to believe that Zenitsu, a supernatural demon slayer, couldn't get out of some rubble, and had to use **First Form: Thunderclap and Flash: God Speed** to get out of about 50kg of rubble, while he is perfectly capable of fighting demons who can lift many times that weight i.e 50kg. Isn't that a contradiction?

Comment: I'd like to argue that 1. demon slayers are not supernatural, demons are 2. If you were under a rubble, you would have struggled just like Zenitsu did unless you have breathing techniques mastered.

Comment: @FumikageTokoyami thanks for your reply! Why are you not of the opinion that demon slayers are supernatural? He's not only fast and strong, literally lightning comes out of Zenitsu's blade!

Comment: Because they are humans.

Comment: lightning isn't literally coming out of his blade. It's some artistic style. See [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/52921/is-the-water-style-actual-magic-or-is-it-just-a-visualisation/66304#66304)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demon Slayers **are human** that have reached an expert level of swordsmanship and breathing techniques similar to real-life samurais, so **they are in no way supernatural**, but the show depicts them using flashy abilities with elemental-like features for entertainment purposes.

Zenitsu was heavily beaten by an Upper Rank Demon and collapsed under a pile of rubble. He uses the breathing technique to get out as it was the only way **to amass enough strength** to free himself and use First Form: Thunderclap and Flash: God Speed to **cover the distance between him and Daki** in an instant.